# Is there a way to add objects from a listbox to a list?

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I am trying to add objects from my listbox into a List.

The following code is how I was attempting it but when I try to add the variables inside the List it throws a Null Exception.

The List is titled games

Game is a custom class.

```
foreach(var item in collectionListBox.Items)
        {
            games.Add(item as Game);
        }
```

Comment: Whats the details of the exception? And how were the items added to the listbox?

Comment: It is a NullReferenceException and the Listbox was populated from the List with a foreach(Game g in games){collectionListBox.Items.Add(g.ToString());}

Comment: How did you populate the listbox at first? Looks like the `item` is not able to convert to Game object.

Comment: I just changed the way I am adding to the Listbox with collectionListBox.Items.Add(Games.ToString());

Comment: To be honest I am trying to update the list after deleting an object from the sorted version of the list in the listbox

Comment: How listbox items can be Object type please show your complete code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It is a NullReferenceException and the Listbox was populated from the List with a foreach(Game g in games){collectionListBox.Items.Add(g.ToString());}

Since you added them like that, your listbox has a bunch of `string`s in it because you added them using `Add(g.ToString())`. Then when you are pulling them out you have the code below where you are traversing the items in the listbox and then calling `item as Game` but `item` is a `string` so that is not possible:

```
foreach(var item in collectionListBox.Items)
{            
    games.Add(item as Game);
}
```

You have to do this instead:

```
foreach(var item in collectionListBox.Items)
{            
    games.Add(item.ToString());
}
```

Comment: I get the error reading cannot convert from string to the object

Comment: Where do you get that error? Is the line number in the code in the answer or elsewhere?

Comment: the line error is for the line that has games.Add(item.ToString());

Comment: That is not possible: A `string` can always be converted to an `object`. I think you are misreading the error. What kind of items are you keeping in `games`?

Comment: I actually have decided to switch from the ListBox to a ListView, seems to be alot more easier to do what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: But to answer your question games list holds the instanciated class of Game inside of it which had a title string, cost decimal, hours played decimal, platform string, and a bool of the game being completed

Comment: Well then there is the issue: `games` is a list of `Game` so you cannot add a `string` to it. All you have to do is to make sure that the listbox has the same type as the `games`. This has nothing to do with using a listview or a listbox.

Comment: giving you the correct answer for this, for your attempt at helping me. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to use a Listview and add the objects from the listview into the list using the objects tag property.